# How to transform object map to array with Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'd like to transfrom the following object:

```
{
  'id-1': { prop: 'val1' },
  'id-2': { prop: 'val2' },
}
```

To array:

```
[
  { id: 'id-1', prop: 'val1' },
  { id: 'id-2', prop: 'val2' },
]
```

What I have done so far (it works):

```
R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(([id, props]) => ({
    id,
    ...props,
  }))
)
```

I'd like to solve it using Ramda only - if possible.

Comment: what do you get with what you have so far?

Comment: It works as expected. I'd like to replace the function passed to `R.map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest that solving it "using Ramda only" is a bad design goal, unless this is an exercise in learning Ramda.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda and a big fan, but Ramda is only a toolkit meant to simplify your code, to make it easier to work in a certain paradigm.

That said, we could certainly write a point-free version of this using Ramda.  The first thing that comes to my mind would be this<sup>*</sup>:

```js
const transform = pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(apply(useWith(merge, [objOf('id'), identity])))
)

const data = {'id-1': { prop: 'val1' }, 'id-2': { prop: 'val2'}}

console.log(transform(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {pipe, toPairs, map, apply, useWith, merge, objOf, identity} = ramda    </script>
```

But this is *less* readable than your original, not more.

This code:

```js
const transform = pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(([id, props]) => ({...props, id}))
)
```

is crystal-clear, whereas that Ramda version requires one to understand Ramda-specific `useWith` and `objOf` and slightly obscure `apply` -- I would hope that `map`, `merge`, and `identity` are clear.

In fact, this code is simple enough that I might well write it as a one-liner, in which case, I switch to `compose` over `pipe`:

```js
const transform = compose(map(([id, props]) => ({...props, id})), toPairs)
```

But I probably wouldn't do so, as I find that multi-line `pipe` version easier to read.

Finally note that we can do this in a fairly readable way without any Ramda tools at all:

```js
const transform = (data) => 
  Object.entries(data).map(
    ([id, props]) => ({...props, id})
  )
```

If I was already using Ramda in my code-base, I would prefer the `pipe` version above to this; I think it's somewhat easier to read.  But would never introduce Ramda into a project only for that fairly minor difference.

I worry that people make a fetish over point-free code.  It's a tool.  Use it when it makes your code more understandable.  Skip it when it makes your code more obscure.  Here I think you're starting from quite readable code; it's difficult to improve on it.

---

<sup>*</sup>**Note** that `identity` here is not strictly necessary; you can skip it with no harm. The function generated by `useWith` without that `identity` will incorrectly report an arity of 1, but since the function is immediately wrapped with `apply` and then further placed in the context of receiving the a two-element array from `toPairs`, there is nothing which depends upon that arity.  But I find it a good habit to include it regardless.

Comment: Many thanks for the grade A answer! This has covered all my concerns with regards to when to and when not to use Ramda. As a side note, I keep stretch using Ramda in order to learn it and be aware of its building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?
probably less verbose!

```js
const toArray = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(
    R.apply(R.assoc('id')),
  ),
);

const data = {
  'id-1': { prop: 'val1' },
  'id-2': { prop: 'val2' },
};

console.log('result', toArray(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```